# Forecasting Hierarchical Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical

I am trying to perform 6 months forecasting over production data for three power plants, I built my data as an hts object that has 3 levels. However, when I am performing the forecast function and then try to see the accuracy using test data I get the following error: "Error in x - fcasts: non-conformable arrays"

[image]

Furthermore, when I try to apply the "arima" as a forecasting method on the hts object I get the following (the warning message is repeated 9 times, as I have 9 time series in the hts object):

> forecasts <- forecast(data,h = 6 , method = "bu" , fmethod = "arima")
>   [image]

I used the following instructions to get the hts object:

[image]

and the data has the following structure:
[image]
I am not sure where I am going wrong. Anyone can help with some thoughts??

Thank you!

The data:

```
structure(list(LarGroup1 = c(188.3, 187.2, 94.7, 109.2, 202.7, 
146.6, 121.9, 151.3, 111.1, 103.4, 188.1, 168.1, 233.9, 230.7, 
187.1, 0, 98.9, 173.5, 149.4, 168.6, 4.7, 14.8, 91.8, 166.5, 
170.5, 123.6, 85.2, 64.4), LarGroup2 = c(159.1, 127.7, 210.3, 
199.8, 113, 143.4, 144.5, 83.8, 41.6, 35.1, 95.2, 178.2, 241.1, 
236.4, 181.9, 194.3, 196.1, 92.4, 154.6, 78.9, 35.7, 0, 74.5, 
75.1, 140, 142.5, 3.8, 17.5), RibGroup1 = c(49.4, 102.4, 50.8, 
118.8, 108.4, 139.5, 121.7, 69.6, 53.4, 28, 113.3, 96.3, 70.8, 
124.4, 54.4, 128.7, 63.3, 2.1, 41.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 5.4, 57.9, 
9.9, 30, 221, 167.2), RibGroup2 = c(32.7, 32, 98.1, 6.3, 85.5, 
96.6, 41.1, 44.9, 50.4, 27.3, 0, 45.4, 199.1, 179.2, 86.1, 0, 
58.4, 43.3, 41.8, 42.1, 22.1, 11.8, 71.8, 112, 204.1, 40.9, 24.5, 
210.9), RibGroup3 = c(90.8, 15.4, 10.5, 124.4, 33.9, 8.4, 38.3, 
56.9, 13.5, 0, 32.6, 132.8, 160.7, 168.7, 60.7, 131.9, 110.8, 
29.2, 131.3, 62.1, 6.1, 0, 0, 3.4, 23.9, 192.7, 165.5, 0), SinGroup1 = c(235.2, 
225.4, 226.1, 234.4, 222.1, 232.3, 233.4, 201.9, 195.3, 209.4, 
233.6, 223.6, 222.2, 232, 224, 149.8, 201.6, 220.2, 203.1, 212.1, 
71.9, 82.3, 183.2, 210.6, 198.6, 230.8, 218, 163.2), SinGroup2 = c(233.4, 
225.6, 227, 51.6, 76, 230.7, 233.1, 202.7, 200.2, 207.2, 228.4, 
226.2, 183.9, 230.4, 222.3, 227.7, 177.9, 152, 218.6, 210.6, 
80.9, 63.2, 188.1, 209.5, 233.2, 210.1, 226.5, 200.5), SinGroup3 = c(233.2, 
188.5, 226.9, 234.7, 222.8, 234.6, 220.6, 156.4, 209.2, 218.7, 
232.9, 226.1, 215.4, 231, 222.7, 222.7, 183.7, 203.8, 216.8, 
112, 0, 39.6, 180.8, 203.6, 221.1, 228.9, 202.8, 186.7), SinGroup4 = c(218, 
215.5, 226.8, 235.6, 223.6, 234.8, 234.9, 69.3, 192, 207.8, 235.2, 
217.2, 235.1, 231.8, 223.5, 230.5, 225.6, 220.1, 220, 211.9, 
114.8, 44.5, 158.5, 206.3, 231.8, 179, 225.3, 198.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

Comment: I don't know much about hierarchical time-series. Try reading https://otexts.org/fpp2/hierarchical.html about them. This online book is written by Rob Hyndman and explains step-by-step how to run a hierarchical forecast using `hts`.

Comment: When I create a `data` variable using your pasted `data.frame`, then call `forecasts <- forecast(data, h=6, method="bu")`, I get a different error: "Error in ets(object, lambda = lambda, biasadj = biasadj, allow.multiplicative.trend = allow.multiplicative.trend,  :   y should be a univariate time series".  Is there more detail we're missing?

Comment: @hmhensen I am following the chapters of this book, and I restructured my data based on the data set used in the example but still, I am not getting the results that I wish for.

Comment: My main problem is applying the accuracy function, since what I need to do is comparing several method and choose the most fit one to the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the accuracy function, you need to include test data, not training data. You ask for 6 steps ahead, but your test data only consists of 4 time periods.
2. The seasonal differencing error suggests you are using an old version of the forecast package. Please update your packages.

The following code works using current CRAN packages (forecast v8.4, hts v

```
library(hts)
Production_data <- data.frame(
  LarGroup1 = c(
    188.3, 187.2, 94.7, 109.2, 202.7,
    146.6, 121.9, 151.3, 111.1, 103.4, 188.1, 168.1, 233.9, 230.7,
    187.1, 0, 98.9, 173.5, 149.4, 168.6, 4.7, 14.8, 91.8, 166.5,
    170.5, 123.6, 85.2, 64.4
  ), LarGroup2 = c(
    159.1, 127.7, 210.3,
    199.8, 113, 143.4, 144.5, 83.8, 41.6, 35.1, 95.2, 178.2, 241.1,
    236.4, 181.9, 194.3, 196.1, 92.4, 154.6, 78.9, 35.7, 0, 74.5,
    75.1, 140, 142.5, 3.8, 17.5
  ), RibGroup1 = c(
    49.4, 102.4, 50.8,
    118.8, 108.4, 139.5, 121.7, 69.6, 53.4, 28, 113.3, 96.3, 70.8,
    124.4, 54.4, 128.7, 63.3, 2.1, 41.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 5.4, 57.9,
    9.9, 30, 221, 167.2
  ), RibGroup2 = c(
    32.7, 32, 98.1, 6.3, 85.5,
    96.6, 41.1, 44.9, 50.4, 27.3, 0, 45.4, 199.1, 179.2, 86.1, 0,
    58.4, 43.3, 41.8, 42.1, 22.1, 11.8, 71.8, 112, 204.1, 40.9, 24.5,
    210.9
  ), RibGroup3 = c(
    90.8, 15.4, 10.5, 124.4, 33.9, 8.4, 38.3,
    56.9, 13.5, 0, 32.6, 132.8, 160.7, 168.7, 60.7, 131.9, 110.8,
    29.2, 131.3, 62.1, 6.1, 0, 0, 3.4, 23.9, 192.7, 165.5, 0
  ), SinGroup1 = c(
    235.2,
    225.4, 226.1, 234.4, 222.1, 232.3, 233.4, 201.9, 195.3, 209.4,
    233.6, 223.6, 222.2, 232, 224, 149.8, 201.6, 220.2, 203.1, 212.1,
    71.9, 82.3, 183.2, 210.6, 198.6, 230.8, 218, 163.2
  ), SinGroup2 = c(
    233.4,
    225.6, 227, 51.6, 76, 230.7, 233.1, 202.7, 200.2, 207.2, 228.4,
    226.2, 183.9, 230.4, 222.3, 227.7, 177.9, 152, 218.6, 210.6,
    80.9, 63.2, 188.1, 209.5, 233.2, 210.1, 226.5, 200.5
  ), SinGroup3 = c(
    233.2,
    188.5, 226.9, 234.7, 222.8, 234.6, 220.6, 156.4, 209.2, 218.7,
    232.9, 226.1, 215.4, 231, 222.7, 222.7, 183.7, 203.8, 216.8,
    112, 0, 39.6, 180.8, 203.6, 221.1, 228.9, 202.8, 186.7
  ), SinGroup4 = c(
    218,
    215.5, 226.8, 235.6, 223.6, 234.8, 234.9, 69.3, 192, 207.8, 235.2,
    217.2, 235.1, 231.8, 223.5, 230.5, 225.6, 220.1, 220, 211.9,
    114.8, 44.5, 158.5, 206.3, 231.8, 179, 225.3, 198.6
  )
)
Production_data_ts <- ts(Production_data, frequency = 12, start = c(2016, 7))
Production_data_hts <- hts(Production_data_ts, characters = c(3, 6))
data <- window(Production_data_hts, start = c(2016, 7), end = c(2018, 6))
test <- window(Production_data_hts, start = c(2018, 7), end = c(2018, 10))
forecasts <- forecast(data, h = 4, method = "bu")
accuracy(forecasts, test)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I posted the wrong picture of the forecast, the error is the same even when I do : 
> accuracy.gts(forecsts, test)

Regarding the second point, R studio is saying that the all packages are up to date when I try to update them.

Comment: I've added code that works using current CRAN packages. Perhaps you are also using a very old version of R, so you can't update to current CRAN packages.

Comment: My code worked just fine when I changed h=6 to  h=4, but I would really like to ask you for an explanation..because I tried before to split the data into two equal parts (14 months for train, and 14 months for test) and h was 6...but still I got the same error... Can you please provide me with an explanation or a link that can explain this relation between the the h and the test period?   Thank you!

Comment: Your test period is July-October 2018. That is 4 months.